# Show or hide custom data set

Tags: 7, users, civicrm

I'm using CIVCRM module in Drupal, and I have created multiple custom data sets for Drupal registration form.

Now problem is that I have 4 membership levels and each level have custom data set so I need to hide other data set and show only those related to selected member level.

Is there a way to do that through administration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Some forms in CiviCRM (ex: contribution/membership) may have some show/hide options, for, say, organisational memberships, but in general, it's not possible to do it using the admin interface, and doing it programmatically with jQuery is recommended.

Another option, is to use the [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) and [webform_civicrm](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) Drupal modules to create a custom form. The latest version of webform_civicrm makes it possible to pretty much rewrite most of the contribution/membership forms. Webform has ways to show/hide fields conditionally.

If you want to do it the jQuery way, depending on whether it is a Drupal form (ex: user registration form), or a CiviCRM form (contribution/membership form), you can put the javascript snippet in your Drupal theme, or in a CiviCRM template.

For example, if it's a Drupal form, you can put it in the equivalent of sites/example.org/themes/mytheme/js/custom.js :

```
/**
 * Show/hide the appropriate custom fields for a membership level.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.myThemeToggleMembershipFields = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#my_membership_type_input').change(function() {
      var v = $(this).val();

      if (v == 1) {
        $('..fields for type 1..').show();
        $('.. other fields..').hide();
      }
      else if (v == 2) {
        // etc.
      }          
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```